# How to get a conditioned MAX from dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to get the max value from a dataframe column based on specific condition, using spark scala please.

We have column "a" and column "b"
I want to get the max value of each column but with this condition :
if column "a" contains 1, then 1 , otherwise max("a")
max("b")
There is an exemple :

```
df :                      res:
+---+---+                 +------+------+
|  a|  b|                 |  maxA|  maxB|
+---+---+                 +------+------+
|  1|  4|                 |     1|     5|
|  4|  3|                 +------+------+
|  6|  5|
|  8|  1|
+---+---+


    df :                   res:
+---+---+                 +------+------+
|  a|  b|                 |  maxA|  maxB|
+---+---+                 +------+------+
|  0|  4|                 |     8|     5|
|  4|  3|                 +------+------+
|  6|  5|
|  8|  1|
+---+---+
```

I have tried this but didn't work :

```
val res = df.agg(max(
            when(col("a").contains(1),lit(1))
            .otherwise(col("a")))
            .as("maxA")
            ,max("b").as("maxB")
            )
```

I NEED TO WRITE MY CONDITION INSIDE THE AGG MAX FUNCTION PLEASE, NOT OUTSIDE.

Comment: Why do you need to do that in the aggregate? I may be wrong but don't see how to achieve it inside the aggregate and I don't see why this would be important.

Comment: If I were to do it, I'd use a reduce operation.

Comment: replace the `lit(1)` with `lit(a number larger than any other number in your df)` so that you know that you've seen a `1`.

Comment: Yes the solution proposed by @werner worked for me. 
I had to put lit(999) for example as the max value and then I added a withcolumn when we have 999 then we replace it by 1.
That's it. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 3):

### Why your approach doesn't work

Let's see the output of `when(col("a").contains(1), lit(.otherwise(col("a"))`:

```scala
df.select(col("a"), when(col("a").contains(1), lit(1)).otherwise(col("a"))).show()
```

```
+---+------------------------------------------+
|  a|CASE WHEN contains(a, 1) THEN 1 ELSE a END|
+---+------------------------------------------+
|  1|                                         1|
|  2|                                         2|
|  4|                                         4|
|  9|                                         9|
+---+------------------------------------------+
```

As you can see, the output column is the same. So basically, it doesn't do anything at all.

### How to do what you want

If you want to do it only in one `.agg` it's not possible with default spark aggregation functions. The good news is that we can implement our custom aggregation function (check [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-udf-aggregate.html) out):

```scala
import scala.math

import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import spark.implicits._

val df = spark.createDataset(Seq(
  (1, 6),
  (2, 0),
  (4, 3),
  (9, 1))
).select(col("_1").as("a"), col("_2").as("b"))

case class Buffer(var max: Int, var oneFound: Boolean)

object MaxIfNo1Found extends Aggregator[Int, Buffer, Int] {

    def zero: Buffer = Buffer(Int.MinValue, false)

    def reduce(buffer: Buffer, value: Int): Buffer = {
        buffer.max = math.max(buffer.max, value) 
        buffer.oneFound = buffer.oneFound | value == 1
        buffer
    }
    
    def merge(b1: Buffer, b2: Buffer): Buffer = {
        b1.max = math.max(b1.max, b2.max)
        b1.oneFound = b1.oneFound | b2.oneFound
        b1
    }

    def finish(reduction: Buffer): Int = if (reduction.oneFound) 1 else reduction.max

    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Buffer] = Encoders.product

    def outputEncoder: Encoder[Int] = Encoders.scalaInt
}

spark.udf.register("maxIfNo1Found", functions.udaf(MaxIfNo1Found))

df.agg(expr("maxIfNo1Found(a)").as("maxA"), max("b").as("maxB")).show
```

```
+----+----+
|maxA|maxB|
+----+----+
|   1|   6|
+----+----+
```

And there it is!

### How it makes more sense to do it

Defining a custom aggregation seems pretty unnecessary. Just do this:

```scala
df.agg(
    max("a").as("maxA"),
    expr("bool_or(a = 1)").as("oneFound"),
    max("b").as("maxB")
  )
  .select(
    when(col("oneFound"), lit(1))
      .otherwise(col("maxA")).as("maxA"),  
    col("maxB")
  )
  .show
```

```
+----+----+
|maxA|maxB|
+----+----+
|   1|   6|
+----+----+
```

[`bool_or`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-functions-builtin.html#aggregate-functions) is an aggregation function that computes boolean logical or through all elements of a given column. In this case if there is just one element in `a` column equal to `1`, `oneFound` will be `True`. For it to be `False` you need all values of column `a` to be different from `1` (Only one `true` will make the hole  expression evaluate to `true`). At the end, you select `1` or `maxA` depending on the value of `oneFound`.

Comment: Max over a Boolean value sounds a bit "risky", may be worth explaining the reasoning and why it works ;)

Comment: Changed `max` to `bool_or`. Why do you say that doing `max` over Boolean sounds risky? Am I missing something?

Comment: What's the max value between true and false is not obvious and may be different in some languages/Frameworks I guess. Max value of integer is more explicit.

Answer (score -1):

```
df.select(
    when(max($"a" === lit(1)), lit(1)).otherwise(max("a")).as("maxA"),
    max($"b").as("maxB")
  )
```

Comment: hi, please could you provide an explanation in your post so future readers can see the issue?

Comment: Code is quite short, and self-explaining; explanations will only waist readers time. Maybe, you have questions about implementation, I can provide answer.